# How to get all data from collection

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get all the data from the first document and move to the next document and do the same.

```
CollectionReference fstore = fs.collection("Diagnostics").document(email).collection("Date");
fstore.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshot) {
        if(!documentSnapshot.isEmpty()){
            for (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshots : documentSnapshot) {
                String date = documentSnapshots.getId();
                String faultcodes = documentSnapshots.getString("Code");
                String description = documentSnapshots.getString("Description");
                TroubleCodes pastsc = new TroubleCodes(date,faultcodes,description);
                pastscan.add(pastsc);
                pastscansdpt.setAdapter(new PastScanAdapter(pastscan, PastScanpage.this));

            }
        }
        else{
            TroubleCodes nosc = new TroubleCodes("No Diagnosis Scans",null, null);
            pastscan.add(nosc);
            pastscansdpt.setAdapter(new PastScanAdapter(pastscan, PastScanpage.this));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: And what is a library?

Comment: What do you mean by library?

Comment: I didn't use `CollectionReference` and `QuerySnapshot`, so don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating and setting adapter for `RecyclerView` or `ListView` for each document over and over again, create your adapter and set it for `RecyclerView` or `ListView` with empty pastscan List just only one time. Then get your data, add in to list and notify the adapter.

```
   pastscansdpt.setAdapter(new PastScanAdapter(pastscan, PastScanpage.this));
    CollectionReference fstore = fs.collection("Diagnostics/" + email + "/Date");
    fstore.get().addOnSuccessListener(queryDocumentSnapshots -> {
        //Clear your list otherwise whenever this method triggers it'll add same documents over and over again.
        pastscan.clear();
        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    //According to your codes your document data structure is same as TroubleCodes.
                    //So you don't need to get all fields one by one.
                    TroubleCodes pastsc = document.toObject(TroubleCodes.class);
                    //Add each document in to your list.
                    pastscan.add(item);
                }
            }
        } else {
            TroubleCodes nosc = new TroubleCodes("No Diagnosis Scans", null, null);
            pastscan.add(nosc);
        }
        //Notify your adapter.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    });
```